# TypeORM Logs To The Console But Doesn't Return

Tags: postgresql, typescript, koa, typeorm

I am building a basic API with Koa, TypeORM and Postgres. The following query inside a `@Get` request is logging the random result to the console **but** is not returning it.

```
@Get("/motivations/random")
async getRandomMotivation() {

    const randomFunc = async () => {

        try {
            let entityManager = await Motivation.getRepository()
                .createQueryBuilder()
                .select("motivations.id")
                .from(Motivation, "motivations")
                .orderBy("RANDOM()")
                .limit(1)
                .getOne()

            console.log("__testing: ", entityManager)
            return await entityManager
        }
        catch (error) {
            console.log("___errorrrrr: ", error)
        }

    }

    return await randomFunc()
}
```

When I fire up the server it first returns an `ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.` error, then it actually loads the server and the database with all tables.
Then, I call the right endpoint, it logs out the random result to the console and when it tries to return the result it returns the following:

```
Connected to Postgres with TypeORM
Listening on port 4000 @ 22:16
query: SELECT "motivations"."id" AS "motivations_id" FROM "motivations" "Motivation", "motivations" "motivations" ORDER BY RANDOM() ASC LIMIT 1
__testing:  Motivation { id: 40 }
query: SELECT "Motivation"."id" AS "Motivation_id", "Motivation"."motivation" AS "Motivation_motivation", "Motivation"."user_id" AS "Motivation_user_id" FROM "motivations" "Motivation" WHERE ("Motivation"."id" = $1) -- PARAMETERS: [null]
query failed: SELECT "Motivation"."id" AS "Motivation_id", "Motivation"."motivation" AS "Motivation_motivation", "Motivation"."user_id" AS "Motivation_user_id" FROM "motivations" "Motivation" WHERE ("Motivation"."id" = $1) -- PARAMETERS: [null]
error: { error: invalid input syntax for integer: "NaN"
.... }
```

As you can see, it runs the random result query and logs it to the console. Then, it runs two queries more with empty parameters ...

Why TypeORM tries to run two additional queries? How do I overcome this issue?

Comment: Does removing the `await` from `return await entityManager` in `randomFunc()` make any difference? You've already `await`ed the promise in `let entityManager = await Motivation.getRepository() ... .getOne()` further above. BTW TypeORM is only running **one** additional query; but it is being logged twice; once to say TypeORM is about to run the query, and the 2nd time because it failed.

Comment: @Timshel, no difference when removed the `await` you mentioned. Also, you are right, it's only one additional query. Still, why does it try to run this extra query? Where does the call for that come from?

Comment: I'm not totally sure why the 2nd query is being run, and your example works locally although I have different models to yours. What version of TypeORM are you using? I suspect TypeORM is running the 2nd query because `.select("motivations.id")` in the query builder means it will only return the `id` column (ie. partial load), so the 2nd query could be being run to load the rest of the object? Try changing `.select("motivations.id")` to just `.select("motivations")` (which will load the full set of properties). Does that make any diffference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
I had two paths - `/motivations/:id` and `/motivations/random`.
However, I forgot to add a check for numbers on `/:id` and because of that whenever I was calling `/random` the server was also calling `/:id` but without any parameter given.
After I changed the path to `/motivations/:id([0-9]+)` the issue is gone. It also turned out that the query to the database was working since the very beginning ...